# Visual studio saves output.txt to wrong directory -> C language

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

I am currently trying to run this very simple code C in visual studio 2013. When I run this code with another IDE (codeblocks) it will create output.txt and put it where ever my main.c is located. I am not able to do this with visual studio. It does not save to my project folder, but a few folders up. I have googled this and can't seem to find a solution.

Basically I would like to have any input or output text files saved in the same folder that visual studio saves the .c file by default (Project folder?).

Anyone familiar with visual studio that can help me out?

Let me know if this needs clarification.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  FILE* fp;

  fp = fopen("output.txt", "w");

  fprintf(fp, "Hello World!");

  fclose(fp);

  return(0);


}
```

thanks!

edit:

For example, the output.txt will save here:  "C:\Users\user\Desktop\learn"

"C:\Users\user\Desktop\learn\professor_example_files\professor_example_files". 
<- my c file is always saved here for example. I am trying to get output.txt to also save here.

Comment: from memory: set Project Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory to the directory you want

Comment: `fopen` will always operate on the current directory if the file name given is not an absolute path. In this case, the current directory is where the binary is run from. If you want it to create in a specific directory then you need to `chdir` to that directory first or give `fopen` an absolute path. Visual studio (and many IDEs) put the compilation output into a seperate location from the code. You can change the Visual studio output directory but I wouldn't recommended doing that - just fix your code or don't rely on such behaviour.